# Camel FTP transfer from local Apache FtpServer of a 15.6 MiB text file took 57 minutes

Tags: apache-camel, ftp-server, camel-ftp, apache-ftpserver

I used the following consumer endpoint in my class running in a JUnit test under Eclipse Oxygen:

```
ftp://anonymous@localhost:21/test?password=****@****&fileName=TEST.TXT
&localWorkDirectory=<FQPN>/in&noop=true&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true
```

The `ftpd.log`:

```
...
[ INFO] 2018-12-15 21:47:48,365 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: PORT 127,0,0,1,198,42
[ INFO] 2018-12-15 21:47:48,365 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 200 Command PORT okay.

[ INFO] 2018-12-15 21:47:48,365 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: RETR TEST.TXT
[ INFO] 2018-12-15 22:44:44,360 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] File downloaded /test/TEST.TXT
[ INFO] 2018-12-15 22:44:44,361 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.

[ INFO] 2018-12-15 22:44:44,361 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 226 Transfer complete.
....
```

I'm using Camel 2.23.0, Apache FtpServer 1.1.1. My Win7 machine has a Windows Experience Index of 7.8 (all components but the CPU have 7.9).

I'm explicitely *not* using:

```
getContext().setStreamCaching(true);
```

in my `RouteBuilder.configure()` but this shouldn't be an issue with 15.6 MiB on localhost, should it?

**UPDATE**

It's the same behaviour with `getContext().setStreamCaching(true)`. Watching `.../in/TEST.TXT.inprogress` shows that its size increases by 8 KiB at about every second.

Comment: Assuming it goes much faster when you download it manually?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti Since this is all on localhost it would be even faster to just copy it. :) But, well, this is not actually for downloading production data. It is for an integration test before actually downloading from production servers.

Comment: Yes but what I mean is that if you use an ftp client locally and get the file, it goes fast? So there is no issue with your ftp server? Otherwise Camel doesn't do anything special except transfer the file.